# Query string selector parsing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a string being passed to jquery like this
    ""

I want to get the value of the bar attribute from the input.

I have

```
var htmlstring = "<input id='foo' type='checkbox' bar='foobar'/><img id='blah' src='blahblah' />";
var bar = $(htmlString).find('input:checkbox').attr("bar");
```

but it doesnt seem to be working?

Any ideas?

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.find()` to `.filter()`.

```
.filter('input:checkbox')
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2QkRm/

This is because the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method  only looks at descendants of the elements at the top level of the jQuery object, whereas the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method looks only at the top level elements.

Also, this may be a typo in the question, but your capitalization changed on your `htmlString` variable.

Comment: @pixelbobby: Yep, love my superscripts! :o)